# .conf file syntax highlighting on neovim

Tags: syntax-highlighting, neovim

I am using Neovim 8.0. previously I used nano, which had syntax highlighting for .conf files. But in neovim there is treesitter for popular languages. I don't know if there are any option for .conf file. So, is there any way to get syntax Highlighting for *.conf* file on **neovim**?

Comment: Hmm, for me `nvim` highlights a conf file without any additional configuration. Might be some distro defaults though *(I'm not on Ubuntu)*. Anyway, can you show what `~/.vimrc` file you're using or do you not have any? In the latter case, try creating a `~/.vimrc` file with this line `syntax on`, then test whether syntax highlight appeared

Comment: Which .conf? Apache?